# ViewPager inside Fragment that Belongs to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an Issue dealing with `ViewPager` inside the `fragment`. Here it is the problem:

I have a `navigation drawer`, contain 4 menu. Each Menu will direct to each `fragment`. In `fragment` from menu number 1, i fill it with `ViewPager`. The application start, i hit menu number 1, everything works fine. Then i go to menu number 2, then back to menu number 1, i got error, and the application force closed.

Do you have any idea what is wrong ? Or maybe ever experience this kind of thing ? 
Thanks for your attention

Here it is my `fragment` from menu number 1 code:

    `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, container);

        pager = (ViewPager)main.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(ft);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.satu, container, false);
    }`

Then here it is the code from main Menu that organize where `fragment` to go when one of the menu clicked.

```
class onListItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            transc = fm.beginTransaction();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(position + "" + text[position]);

            if (position == 0) {
                transc.replace(R.id.drawerContent, new satu());
            } else if (position == 1) {
                transc.replace(R.id.drawerContent, new dua());
            } else if (position == 2) {
                transc.replace(R.id.drawerContent, new tiga());
            } else {
                transc.replace(R.id.drawerContent, new listMenu());
            }
            transc.commit();
        } catch (Exception exx) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + exx.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getChildFragmentManager() instead, since they will be nested inside the fragment containing the ViewPager.